# 2-Node Cluster, Master goes down, Worker fails

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, k3s, traefik-ingress

We have a 2 node K3S cluster with one master and one worker node and would like "reasonable availability" in that, if one or the other nodes goes down the cluster still works i.e. ingress reaches the services and pods which we have replicated across both nodes. We have an external load balancer (F5) which does active health checks on each node and only sends traffic to up nodes.

**Unfortunately, if the master goes down the worker will not serve any traffic (ingress).**

This is strange because all the service pods (which ingress feeds) on the worker node are running.

We suspect the reason is that key services such as the `traefik` ingress controller and `coredns` are only running on the master.

Indeed when we simulated a master failure, restoring it from a backup, none of the pods on the worker could do any DNS resolution. Only a reboot of the worker solved this.

We've tried to increase the number of replicas of the `traefik` and `coredns` deployment which helps a bit BUT:

- This gets lost on the next reboot
- The worker still functions when the master is down but every 2nd ingress request fails

  - It seems the worker still blindly (round-robin) sends traffic to a non-existant master

We would appreciate some advice and explanation:

- Should not key services such as `traefik` and `coredns` be DaemonSets by default?
- How can we change the service description (e.g. replica count) in a persistent way that does not get lost
- How can we get intelligent traffic routing with ingress to only "up" nodes
- Would it make sense to make this a 2-master cluster?

UPDATE: Ingress Description:

```
kubectl describe ingress -n msa
Name:             msa-ingress
Namespace:        msa
Address:          10.3.229.111,10.3.229.112
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found>)
TLS:
  tls-secret terminates service.ourdomain.com,node1.ourdomain.com,node2.ourdomain.com
Rules:
  Host                           Path  Backends
  ----                           ----  --------
  service.ourdomain.com
                                /   gateway:8443 (10.42.0.100:8443,10.42.1.115:8443)
  node1.ourdomain.com
                                /   gateway:8443 (10.42.0.100:8443,10.42.1.115:8443)
  node2.ourdomain.com
                                /   gateway:8443 (10.42.0.100:8443,10.42.1.115:8443)
Annotations:                     kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
                                traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.middlewares: msa-middleware@kubernetescrd
Events:                          <none>
```

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster (your config file)? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud provider? It is important to reproduce your problem.

Comment: K3S bare metal 1.22.7 stable

Comment: What do you mean "Only "up" nodes"? You can use [`ReplicaSet`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/replicaset/#how-a-replicaset-works) to achieve your goal.

Comment: We do indeed have a ReplicaSet and a Deployment of 2 instances. The pods run on each server but when one server (the master) goes down, the second server is still load balancing traffic to it so 50% traffic fails.

Comment: Well, than I have to ask. How did you set up the cluster (your config files)? Can you provide the output of the command `kubectl describe ingress <“ingress name”>`. It is important to reproduce your problem.

Comment: I've posted the describe ingress results (redacted). We are using k3s pretty standard, no special config just `curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | bash`. In the above the `gateway` service is a custom nginx DaemonSet which routes to our microservices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your goals seems can be achievable with a few K8S internal features (not specific to Traffic):

1. Assure you have 1 replica of [Ingress Controller's Pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers/) on each Node => use [Daemon Set](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/) as a installation method
2. To fix the error from Ingress Description set the correct load Balancer IP of Ingress Controller's Service.
3. Use external Traffic Policy to "Local" - this assures that traffic is routed to local endpoints only (Controller Pads running on Node accepting traffic from Load Balancer)

> `externalTrafficPolicy` - denotes if this Service desires to route external traffic to node-local or cluster-wide endpoints. There are two available options: `Cluster` (default) and `Local`. `Cluster` obscures the client source IP and may cause a second hop to another node, but should have good overall load-spreading. `Local` preserves the client source IP and avoids a second hop for LoadBalancer and NodePort type Services, but risks potentially imbalanced traffic spreading.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: example-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: example
  ports:
    - port: 8765
      targetPort: 9376
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  type: LoadBalancer
```

5. Service name of Ingress Backend should use [external Traffic Policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/) `externalTrafficPolicy: Local` too.

Comment: Could you answer me, did my decision help you? If yes, you could follow [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) recommendations for evaluating responses.

Comment: Your advice looks promising. I have patched the `kube-system/traefik` service in K3S to `externalTrafficPolicy: Local` and now see that I can target specific nodes - inbound traffic from LB to Ingress Controller remains on the node. Unfortunately my Ingress targets another (custom) Nginx which has upstream services (type ClusterIP) and this is only 50% available when one node is down.

Comment: Small correction, our Nginx takes a 30 seconds and then becomes 100% available. I guess there is some timeout before K3S marks a node (or pod replica) as unavailable.

Comment: So there seems to be a difference depending on whether the master or the worker is rebooted. If the master is booted we have 50% availability for 2.5min. If the worker is booted we have 50% availability for 30s.

Comment: could you explain what you mean here: "To fix the error from Ingress Description set the correct load Balancer IP of Ingress Controller's Service."

Comment: I meant that you need to check whether the IP address of your load Balancer is correctly specified in the Ingress Service. Using  `kubectl get services LoadBalancer`

Comment: The LoadBalancer for the Service "traefik" has 2 IPs - i.e. both of my nodes are there. This does not change if one node goes down. Could you explain why Kubernetes needs to know these IPs and how they are used. Our load balancer is external - kubernetes does not need to know about it IMO.

Comment: I ask you to create a new question on this topic so it will be right. And it will allow other community members to better get into the problem and not look for everything in the comments .

Comment: Your answer said to "set the correct load Balancer IP". I am asking for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Running single node or two node masters in k8s cluster is not recommended and it doesnt tolerate failure of master components. Consider running 3 masters in your kubernetes cluster.

Following link would be helpful -->
https://netapp-trident.readthedocs.io/en/stable-v19.01/dag/kubernetes/kubernetes_cluster_architecture_considerations.html

Comment: It may not be ideal but at least there is always a master available. Currently my worker does not know that a pod is gone because there is no master to query.

Comment: Indeed High-Availability is possible with only 2 Nodes if the data store (e.g. etcd) is external (and HA).